# How to handle favicon.ico in headless selenium with xvfb

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have the various scenarios of selenium test script which is properly running on selenium web driver with firefox browser. when i running them in headless mode some of scenarios are running but some of them are not running some time but most of time it fails and throw the error like

```
onhandlernotfound/favicon.ico
```

and

```
pagenotfound/favicon.ico[onhandlernotfound/favicon.ico]
```

the screenshot attached - [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tu6q.png) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiedS.png).
Give me the solution as soon as possible

my test case failed and get the error that element is not currently visible so may not be interacted with

```
element is not currently visible so may not be interacted with
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get favicon internet-path and try to download it(externally, not via the selenium).

If favicon will be not accessible -- there will be no ability to download. If its is accessible -- its will be shown in any of browser (in case of enabled images) =)

Maybe this is not the best way, but this will work.

As you didnt write your language, I can give you code to download image for c#:

```
string webPath = ""; /*favicon internet path*/
if (webPath != string.Empty)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(webPath);
        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap bitmapImg = new Bitmap(responseStream);
        return bitmapImg;
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {
    }
}
```